# How to identify a Time Lord?

Tags: doctor-who, time-lord

> ROSE: Well, he's got two hearts.
>   JACKIE: Oh, don't be stupid.
>   ROSE: He has.
>   JACKIE: Anything else he's got two of?
>   <sub>(*The Christmas Invasion*, 2005 Christmas special)</sub>

So *is* there anything else he's got two of? Or to put it more generally, **what are the physiological differences between a human and a Time Lord, other than the number of hearts?** How can you tell, just from examining a Time Lord's body, that he - or she - is a Time Lord?

Let's say you can't kill the person to see whether they regenerate, nor can you wait hundreds of years to see whether they die of old age. All you can do is a one-off examination of their body. You have all the equipment you need: stethoscopes and so forth. So that you can see the whole of their body (as well as to exclude the possibility of identifying a Time Lord by their dress sense), let's assume they're naked:

[image: naked Doctor]

Comment: Kill him. If he regenerates, he's guilty of being a Time Lord. If he stays dead... then he was innocent.

Comment: @Omegacron What if he's in his final regeneration (and doesn't have a handy bunch of Gallifreyans behind a crack in the sky to give him a new regeneration cycle)?

Comment: Easy, by their [eccentric dress sense](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/80/Versions_of_the_Doctor.jpg/275px-Versions_of_the_Doctor.jpg).

Comment: @randal'thor well, just to be safe, if he stays dead you can cut him open and see how many hearts he had.

Comment: @Wikis I've edited to make it clearer what I'm asking. I hope Matt Sith's naked torso isn't considered too NSFW for this site?

Comment: "Matt Sith" ... I'm picking up Star Wars knowledge by osmosis on this site! :-O

Comment: I would imagine a DNA sample would reveal differences from human DNA.  Humans don't have DNA for two hearts, regeneration, etc...

Comment: @randal'thor: fine. shoot all my theories down. see if i care.

Comment: Do you want only the physiological differences mentioned on the show, or ones invented in other media like audios and books? Either way, it should just be a matter of going through the seemingly very complete [Gallifreyan physiology](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Gallifreyan_physiology) article on the Doctor Who wiki and looking for relevant sentences...

Comment: 75k yet, rand?:)

Comment: @AJL Yay, thanks :-) But it's 7.5k, not 75k - Slytherincess is the 75k-er here!

Comment: Oops, oh yes…  Typos galore on these comments ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Lord#Physical_characteristics) so take it for what it is, but the main differences are:

> Physiological differences from humans include two hearts which normally beat at 170 beats per minute, an internal body temperature of 15 degrees Celsius (59 degrees Fahrenheit) and a "respiratory bypass system" that allows them to survive strangulation. Time Lords can also survive full exposure to the vacuum of space with no ill effects, though when in a vacuum for an extended period, a Time Lord must take a supply of air along or suffocate. Time Lords also seem to have an increased resilience to higher frequencies of sound, as seen in "The Christmas Invasion" and "Partners in Crime". If severely injured, Time Lords can go into a healing coma which lowers their body temperature to below freezing.

So according to this, a simple temperature test will do. If you're still not sure, throw him to outer space and see how long it takes him to suffocate.

Some of these facts are marked as "citation needed". Others are referenced to different episodes of classic Who and new Who.

Comment: Does anybody have a source for that body temperature statement? Wikipedia page itself lacks that particular citation.

Comment: “Time Lords can also survive full exposure to the vacuum of space with no ill effects” — weeeeell, sometimes they go blind.

Comment: They can also survive freezing temperatures way below human range "DOCTOR: Stasis chamber. You've got to take it below minus two hundred. Freeze it out of me! It'll use me to kill you if you don't."  Season 3, Episode 7 (42 minutes)

Comment: There was a 2nd Doctor story that mention the body temp, but I don't recall which.  Also, the novelization of "Mark of the Rani" mentions it as well.  (It was how the Rani recognized the Doctor as a Time Lord.)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming a brief (relatively) non-harmful physiological examination with commonly available 21st century human medical tools ...

Aside from the 2 heartbeats...
which might not be unique to Gallifreyan physiology, heck even [one our own species has had 2 hearts](http://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/health-and-families/health-news/miracle-of-the-girl-with-two-hearts-1744960.html)!

Also assuming they haven't had a "dodgy" regeneration and are missing a head or have a dog's nose (according to comments by the 9th Doctor)....

If you stuck a light down their throat you might see evidence of their "[Respiratory bypass system](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Respiratory_bypass_system)".

Comment: I've always taken that "missing a head" thing to be a case of Rule 1: The Doctor Lies.

Comment: The tricky bit is that the Doctor sometimes tells outrageous truths.

Comment: When you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth. - Sherlock Holmes

Comment: Missing a head is very common. Some Time Lords have as few as one head. These tend to be overrepresented in the military and political arenas of Time Lord society.