# Is there an in-universe explanation for why humans look like Time Lords?

Tags: doctor-who, time-lord

> **Amy:** You look human.
>
> **Doctor:** No, you look Time Lord.  We came first.
>
> (from Series 5, episode 2, *The Beast Below*)

Is there an in-universe explanation for why Time Lords and humans look exactly the same?

Comment: Related (not dupe): [How to identify a Time Lord?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/95583/21267)