# What are the superpowers of The Doctor other than Regeneration?

Tags: doctor-who

The Doctor occasionally shows his superpowers. Here are some examples:

- In the pilot episode *Rose* of Doctor Who (2005), 9th Doctor read a book very quickly.
- In the second episode *The End of the World* of Doctor Who (2005), 9th Doctor closed his eyes and passed between blades of a running fan quickly.
- 9th Doctor sucked Time Vortex from Rose and returned it to TARDIS.
- 10th Doctor grew his hand in regeneration phase.
- 10th Doctor touched Reinettes head to read her mind.
- 10th Doctor erased the memory of Donna by touching her head.
- 10th Doctor became young using people's prayer.
- 11th Doctor healed River Song's broken hand (using little bit regeneration energy).
- 11th Doctor gave a man his memories by bumping his head into him.

What is the full list (a finite list) of The Doctor's superpowers?

Comment: Any power the script requires. That includes features for his magic wand...errr...sonic screwdriver.

Comment: Not a dupe, but related: the first answer to this question (characteristics of a timelord): https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95583/how-to-identify-a-time-lord

Comment: The ability to talk his way out of most situations.  The ability to see what are fixed points in time https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66376/is-the-doctor-omniscient-or-was-he-bluffing?rq=1

Comment: "which should be finite" - Just where did you get that idea?  The list is not finite and never has been.

Comment: @Kevin No. of superpowers possessed by him can be infinite, but if we pick only those which are shown on-screen, it's ofcourse going to be finite.

Comment: He can also survive if one of he's heart is stopped (episode with shakespear) but its not a superpower, only a time lord thing because they have 2 hearts...

Comment: Telepathy with doors !

Answer (score 8):

It has been implied at times that the Doctor is rather like Superman - he's constantly holding back.

A non-canon description is found in the audio play *When Death Comes to Time*, in which Ace is being trained to become a Time Lord. One of her trials is to cross an underground lake without touching the deadly red liquid of the lake. She has to jump from one stalagmite to another, balancing precariously all the way.

She finally falls in and panics as the red liquid douses her. Her guide explains that the liquid is exactly the same as water, except in one regard: It is red. She realises that there is no danger at all. Her guide then asks her if, knowing that, she could still make herself cross the lake the hard way, by hopping across the stalagmites.

The Doctor is known to have astonishing potential abilities. He can sense effectively everything around him, he can end a politician's career with six words, he can freeze his enemies eternally in place as scarecrows. He can trap people in reflections, can make them immortal but trap them eternally. He can channel incredible amounts of psychic energy if it's available...but he tries not to. He's like a giant living in a world full of children - he daren't use anything like his actual strength, for fear of destroying those around him.

All the powers that he has displayed are likely to be part of a more general power set, but we don't know what that power set is. Likely we'll never know; likely we never *could* know.

All of which is a long way of saying "He has the powers that the plot demands, and doesn't use powers when the plot demands tension."

Comment: Other than the physiological advantages (two hearts, respiratory bypass, regeneration), Time Lords are psychic, clever and knowledgeable - that pretty much covers all the powers as presented.